# one level expansion of makefile macro while still usable as a macro

Tags: makefile

I am trying to build a macro in Makefile which I can expand once but can still work as a macro after being expanded. This is useful to me as the first level expansion will fill in recursive parameters that won't last. Here's an example:

```
all: aperiod

TGT = hello
hello.TGT = world
world.TGT = period
define CREATE_TARGET
.SECONDARY: $(1)
$(3)$(1): $(4)$(2)
    @echo $$$$(@)
$(foreach t,$($(1).TGT),$(call CREATE_TARGET,$(t),$(1),$$(1),$$(1)))
endef
define CREATE
$(call CREATE_TARGET,$(TGT),,$$(1),)
endef

CREATE_EXP := $(call CREATE)
TGT :=
$(eval $(call CREATE_EXP,a))
```

Error when running make:
make: *** No rule to make target `aperiod', needed by`all'.  Stop.

TGT contains a changing set of values. I want CREATE_EXP to contain the full expanded creation method which accepts a parameter to give prefixes to the targets.

So optimally, I can call `make aperiod` and get hello world period, or call `make bperiod` after `$(eval $(call CREATE_EXP,b))` and get the same thing

This is a highly reduced test case!

The value of CREATE_EXP is correct, but won't work for me as a macro anymore.

```
$(info $(value CREATE_EXP))

.SECONDARY: hello
$(1)hello: 
    @echo $$(@)
.SECONDARY: world
$(1)world: $(1)hello
    @echo $$(@)
.SECONDARY: period
$(1)period: $(1)world
    @echo $$(@)
```

I would like to know why Make behaves this way, as well as if there is a better way to accomplish the general gist of what I am trying to do.

EDIT: I found a solution to accomplish this, although I am still curious as to whether a call to $(call) can create a macro that still needs expansion.

```
define CREATE
define CREATE_EXP
$(call CREATE_TARGET,$(TGT),,$$(1),)
endef
endef
```

Use `$(eval $(call CREATE))`

The first time through, make will expand the variables inside. This allows for the recursive expansion as well as the creation of a function macro.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to think more deeply about "a better way" and really understand what you're trying to do, but to answer "why make behaves this way": you are assigning `CREATE_EXP` as a simply-expanded variable, with `:=`:

```
CREATE_EXP := $(call CREATE)
```

That information is stored along with the variable and when make expands something like `$(CREATE_EXP)` it knows that the value of `CREATE_EXP` has already been expanded and it shouldn't be expanded again.  That's the entire point, really, of using `:=`.

Here's an alternate model that might work for you:

```
$(foreach 1,a,$(eval $(CREATE_EXP)))
```

(I haven't tried this).  The difference here is that first we set the variable `1` as the `foreach` variable, then we call `eval` in that context.  Although the `$(CREATE_EXP)` expands to the value without further expansion, then `eval` will parse it as a makefile and expand it again, with `1=a` set.

Just a note: this:

```
CREATE_EXP := $(call CREATE)
```

Is absolutely identical to this:

```
CREATE_EXP := $(CREATE)
```

If you pass no arguments to `call` it's the same as a simple macro expansion.

You might be interested to read the set of blog posts here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/  (start from the oldest first).